# How to initialize a matrix ONCE in a constexpr constructor?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have the following matrix class:

```cpp
template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
class matrix
{
    float data[Rows][Cols];
public:
    constexpr matrix(const float (&input)[Rows][Cols]) : data{}
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
            std::copy(input[i], input[i] + Cols, data[i]);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
constexpr auto m = matrix({
    {4.3f, 5.0f, 1.2f},
    {8.0f, 1.9f, 6.5f},
    {9.1f, 2.2f, 3.7f},
});
```

[This compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/PFdY7F) (in C++20) and works fine, but it requires initializing `data` twice. The first, `data{}`, is required because everything must be member-initialized in a `constexpr` constructor, and the second copies the actual input.

Initializing twice at compile time doesn't matter, but it also means this constructor can't be used at run-time since it needlessly initializes the same data twice.

Is there anything equivalent to this pseudo code?

```cpp
constexpr matrix(const float (&input)[Rows][Cols])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
        std::constexpr_uninitialized_copy(input[i], input[i] + Cols, data[i]);
}
```

Comment: sorry cannot help myself: You cannot initialize something more than once. (i know what you mean, but the wording is a tiny bit off)

Comment: Can't you use `std::array` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[P1331](https://wg21.link/p1331) (Permitting trivial default initialization in constexpr contexts) was adopted for C++20. It removes the requirement that:

> every non-variant non-static data member and base class subobject shall be initialized

which is what required you to have the `: data {}` initialization.

This should just work:

```
template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
class matrix
{
    float data[Rows][Cols];
public:
    constexpr matrix(const float (&input)[Rows][Cols])
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
            std::copy(input[i], input[i] + Cols, data[i]);
    }
};
```

No need to initialize `data` anymore.

Comment: I see! I guess I'll just have to wait a bit for the compiler devs to catch up.

Comment: @seaplusplus: That's kind of putting the cart before the horse here, since C++20 isn't even done yet.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's not done, but it's feature complete, and I too excited to wait! I'll just settle with whatever trunk gcc can get me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::array`. The only caveat is that you'll need an extra brace pair:

```
template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
class matrix
{
    std::array<std::array<float, Rows>, Cols> data;
public:
    constexpr matrix(std::array<std::array<float, Rows>, Cols> const& input) : data{input} {}
};

template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
matrix(const float (&input)[1][Rows][Cols]) -> matrix<Rows, Cols>;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto m = matrix({{
        {4.3f, 5.0f, 1.2f},
        {8.0f, 1.9f, 6.5f},
        {9.1f, 2.2f, 3.7f},
    }});
}
```

As you can see, `data` is initialized only once

Comment: This is not the case. The compiler cannot elide this: https://godbolt.org/z/7Ha1pa. The double initialization makes a difference when you are working with run time values. Of course, in `constexpr` land, it won't matter. But that wasn't the issue at hand.

Comment: @seaplusplus if declared as inline (which implicitly happen with `constexpr`) then the compiler elides it correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/RPC2zb Edit: only clang does it it seems.

Comment: @seaplusplus I corrected the answer, GCC seem to miss that optimisation yet.

Comment: Clang does not do this optimization either: https://godbolt.org/z/GT7eiN. It calls memset when `data{}` is added. Any test performed with compile time values will yield inaccurate results. You should use function arguments as input to your tests.

Comment: @seaplusplus no it does optimise it when it's inline, which `constexpr` enable implicitly: https://godbolt.org/z/NTwmhm

Comment: I see, I was going based off your godbolt link which has everything optimized away.

Comment: @seaplusplus yeah, adding the undefined `g` function did the trick. I think GCC could really benefit this optimisation too, it's not uncommon to rewrite data quickly after initializing it.